# Flash content works on direct link, but not when inserted into html?

Tags: html, flash-cs4

How come http://www.zolomon.com/wptj/wp-content/themes/default/polaroid.swf 
works perfectly but not when implemented at http://www.zolomon.com/wptj/?page_id=8 ?

The code I use to insert the .swf-file is the following:

```
            <object width="522" height="490" id="polaroid" align="middle">
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
                <param name="movie" value="polaroid.swf" />
                <param name="menu" value="false" />
                <param name="quality" value="high" />
                <param name="scale" value="noscale" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#DFCEAF" />
                <embed src="wp-content/themes/default/polaroid.swf" menu="false" quality="high" scale="noscale" wmode="transparent" bgcolor="#ffffff" width="522" height="490" name="polaroid" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" allowFullScreen="false" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" />
            </object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When inspecting the HTTP requests, your photos.xml has the wrong link. It is requesting:

```
http://www.zolomon.com/wptj/photos.xml
```

And on the working version you are requesting:

```
http://www.zolomon.com/wptj/wp-content/themes/default/photos.xml
```

Make sure the paths is right in the webpage.